# How do you embed third party content in native apps?

Tags: android, ios, appcelerator

I am currently trying to figure out how I can embed third party content such as Twitter and Facebook embeds in a native app.

The API I'm using returns a JSON array of the page information and the content as HTML - it's a news app similar to BBC News, Guardian, Mashable etc..

To me the best way to display this information is in a WebView (is there an alternative?). An example of the HTML returned from the API would be formatted as such

```
<p>This is the first paragaph before the tweet</p>
<blockquote class="twitter-tweet" data-lang="en"><p lang="en" dir="ltr">Five charts you need to see before tomorrow&#39;s Bank of England interest rate   decision 
<a href="https://next.ft.com/content/75575eb8-7969-3d40-a411-db9ef32bb8a3">https://next.ft.com/content/75575eb8-7969-3d40-a411-db9ef32bb8a3</a> <a href="https://twitter.com/FT/status/760832630963208192/photo/1">pic.twitter.com/7tbDFQIIJj</a></p>&mdash; Financial Times (@FT) <a href="https://twitter.com/FT/status/760832630963208192">August 3, 2016</a> </blockquote>
<script async src="https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<p>And the story continues on from here...could have any number of HTML tags <img src=""/> <strong></strong><i></i> and even inline Javascipt or CSS</p>
```

I can get this to render correctly in a webview, however if a user clicks on the tweet it is going to open up on top of the webview and take over the full screen. When really what it should do is open up in the users browser or native app (if available)

It's the same story for Facebook embeds and any iFrame based embeds.

There must be a simple solution for this, I've seen many news apps like the Guardian and Mashable having multiple embedded tweets in their mobile apps that open in a browser or the native app if it's installed.

### What I've tried

I have tried injecting JavaScript to listen and intercept the click events but this isn't possible with the iFrames that are rendered for security reasons. It also seems like a very crude hack to get something that seems so trivial to work.

I have also attempted to listen to the `beforeload` event of the webview to try and intercept loading to remote urls. This works fine if the user clicks on a regular `a href` link, but not if it's an embedded tweet/facebook post

I am currently attempting to build my native app using Appcelerator, while it does use JavaScript, this is to interact with the native components for Android and iOS and I should be able to achieve the same with this as a purely native app would

Have I missed something terribly obvious here?

Comment: I'm trying to better understand your problem - who is giving you the HTML? the twitter/facebook API? or your own API? And why aren't you working against the twitter/facebook graph APIs themselves and making REST calls to get data directly as JSON and parse it in your app in whatever way you with to?

Comment: We have our own API which returns HTML of stories on our site. This HTML will often contain Twitter/Facebook embed code. It seems a bit much to manually be parsing JSON from the API's when the embed code works fine everywhere else, it will still need to be rendered in a webview with the rest of the HTML